# R : For loop / count conditional rows/ data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am new to R. Now I was asked to use a for loop to count the number of
diamonds with color E and clarity SI2 in the first n observations of the diamonds
dataset.

I write my code like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

countESI2<-function(n){
  k<-NULL
  diamonds1<-diamonds[1:n,]
  for (i in 1:n)   {
    if(diamonds1$color=="E" & diamonds1$clarity=="SI2") {
      k<-k+1}
  }
  return(k)
}
countESI2(50)
```

But it did not work, could anyone help me to check it? Many appreciation.

Comment: One issue is `k` initialization: to set something to zero, you initialize it with `k <- 0`, not `NULL`.  The latter is a sort of non-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues here. First, `k` should start at `0`, not `NULL`. `NULL + 1` is equal to `numeric(0)`, not `1` as you probably expected. Second, you need to index into which row of `diamonds` you are interested in. Third, it looks like you are checking for clarify of ST2, not SI2 as stated in the question and function name.

```
countESI2<-function(n){
  k<-0 # Not NULL
  for (i in 1:n)   {
    if(diamonds$color[i]=="E" & diamonds$clarity[i]=="SI2") { # Index by i; change from "ST2"
      k<-k+1}
  }
  return(k)
}
countESI2(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few problems:

1. The `if` statement in your loop makes no use of the `i` variable, so it's logically comparing the entire "color" and "clarity" columns each time.
2. `k` should not be initialized to `NULL` (which does nothing). Instead, set it to 0.
3. The task calls for counting occurrences of "SI2" but your code references "ST2".
4. Since this is a homework assignment, I leave it to you to correct the code yourself.